# Why IsFocused not fired on Label

Tags: c#, wpf, events, xaml, controls

I just want to define a trigger that changes a Label background color when 
focused, but it doesn't work. Doing the same with button is OK. Are there something wrong ?!?! I also got a same problem with Border and textblock.

Update code xaml:

```
  <Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GridLineBrush" Color="#8DAED9" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HeaderWeekDayBackground" Color="#A5BFE1" />
    <Style x:Key="borderStyle" TargetType="Control">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HeaderWeekDayBackground}" />
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Window.Resources>

  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition/>
      <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource borderStyle}" 
        Grid.Row="0" >
    </Button>
    <Label Focusable="True" Style="{StaticResource borderStyle}" 
        Grid.Row="1" >
    </Label>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: How do you intend to give the Label focus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all controls are focusable by default, set `Focusable` to `true` ans see if that helps.

One problem you might encounter is that by default the Label does not receive focus from mouse-events.

I do not know if there is a clean XAML-only way to set the focus but you could handle a mouse-event:

```
<Label Focusable="True" Content="Test" MouseLeftButtonUp="Label_MouseLeftButtonUp">
    <Label.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Label.Style>
</Label>
```

```cs
//Note that this is not a "proper" click.
private void Label_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var label = sender as Label;
    label.Focus();
}
```

Comment: It still not working after set focusable to true<Label Focusable="True" Style="{StaticResource borderStyle}" 
                Grid.Row="1" >
        </Label>

Comment: Please see my code above, it doesnt work. If label or border cant recevie focus from mouse, how to make it does?

Comment: See my comment to your question.

Comment: yeah I see, so how to make it receive focus, I need it highlight after the mouse click

Comment: I added the ugly code-behind option to my answer. XAML only might be difficult.